# IE11 Enterprise Mode Strange Behavior

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I'm currently attempting to get ready for deployment of IE11, doing this involves getting Enterprise Mode enabled because of our ancient intranet apps.

First thing I did was set up an API for it. The purpose of the API is to edit the centrally located XML file, so whenever a user (or admin probably) puts a site in Enterprise Mode via the menu, it

- Edits that XML file appropriately, then
- Increases its version number

This is working perfectly. It updates the file and increases the version number. However, when I launch Internet Explorer, I never see a request go out to the `SiteList` value to check for the file, even after the recommended 65 second wait.

I've double checked and my `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode` key contains the `SiteList` string and it is set to the appropriate URL where the XML file is available. I know the XML file is publicly available because I and my coworkers can navigate to it in my browser. I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the issue, it's partly due to how I was using it.

Whenever I would set Enterprise Mode for a website through the Tools menu, it would successfully submit the POST request to my API and put it in the file accordingly. So for instance the default path for Google images (this was a test case) when I was click on it is `https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en`. So in the file it would be

```
<domain exclude="true">
    www.google.com
    <path exclude="false">imghp?hl=en</path>
</domain>
```

I would never see the request to go out and get the file (I still can't explain why it didn't do this, but it looks like **something** was misconfigured on my side. I fixed it by completely undoing everything I did and re-doing all the steps to enable EM). When I finally got it to start making requests, it wouldn't render anything in EM. This is due to the fact that it was telling me (not telling me, I had to find out on my own through extensive research with process monitor) the XML was invalid due to the path with an "=" sign in it.

So on my POST request that sends the full URL, I told it to strip out any parameters in the URL (anything after '?') and all of the sudden it's working for me and all my coworkers who are helping me test it. So to summarize, don't store any URLs with parameters in the XML file, otherwise it will break.